# Normal coordinate parallel along radial geodesics?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

A radial geodesic in normal coordinates is given by $\gamma:t \mapsto t(V_1,....,V_n).$ Is it then true that any normal coordinate $\partial_x|_{\gamma}$ is parallel along $\gamma,$ i.e. $\nabla_{\gamma'}\partial_x=0$?  I implicitly saw this once in a calculation, but I have never seen this anywhere as a property of normal coordinates, so I guess it is false, but I don't really know.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true. To see why, choose an index $i$ and define a vector field $J$ along $\gamma$ by 
$$
J(t) = t\partial_{x^i}\big|_{\gamma(t)}.
$$
Then $J$ is the variation field of the following family of geodesics:
$$
\gamma_s(t) = (tV_1,\dots,t(V_i+s),\dots,tV_n).
$$
Therefore, $J$ satisfies the Jacobi equation:
$$
\nabla_{\gamma'}\nabla_{\gamma'} J(t) = R(J(t),\gamma'(t))\gamma'(t),
$$
whose right-hand side is not necessarily zero unless the metric is flat.
If $\partial_{x^i}$ were parallel along $\gamma$, then $J$ would satisfy
$$
\nabla_{\gamma'}\nabla_{\gamma'} J(t) =
\nabla_{\gamma'} \left(\partial_{x^i} + t \nabla_{\gamma'} \partial_{x^i}\right)
= 2\nabla_{\gamma'} \partial_{x^i} + t \nabla_{\gamma'}\nabla_{\gamma'} \partial_{x^i}=0.
$$